# Comparing a 2d char array with some actual text in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling, char

So I'm trying to do this program thingy over here for a school project (not really, these are exercises for a c++ competition I'm going to). There are no logical mistakes in my code (as far as i know of), just this one technical one that bugs me.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
char odg[n][n];
int sprt[n];
for(int i = 0; i<n*2; i++){

    cin>>sprt[i] >> odg[i][i];
}

int da[n];
int ne[n];

for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){

        if(odg[i][j]="DA"){    //this one right here

          da[i]=sprt[i];  
        }else{

            ne[i]=sprt[i];
        }
    }
}

int temp;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{       
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(da[i]>da[j])
        {
            temp  =da[i];
            da[i]=da[j];
            da[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}


int temP;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{       
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(ne[i]>ne[j])
        {
            temP  =ne[i];
            ne[i]=ne[j];
            ne[j]=temP;
        }
    }
}

cout<<ne[0]+1<<" "<<da[0]-1;
return 0;
```

}

Basically, how can i check if that 2d char array is DA?

Here's the input you have to, well, input:

4/t
1 NE/t
7 DA/t
3 NE/t
9 DA/t

and here's the expected output:

4 6

Comment: [Edit] your question and add a simple example of input vs. expected and actual output.

Comment: There's a lot of logical mistakes in your code... `cin>>sprt[i] >> odg[i][i];` will write *far beyond* both arrays to begin with. If you are allowed to use `std::vector<std::string>`, use that and save yourself a lot of headache.

Comment: `cin>>n;char odg[n][n];...int da[n];int ne[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by constant expressions, not runtime variables.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector<>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so what you're saying is you can't just set multidimensional arrays as chars like that? Will it be more correct if i set them as different arrays?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen no, im not allowed to use vectors as my memory cap is 64 mb and my max compile time should be 1 second, also wont the cin in in the loop just loop the entire cin 4 times (in the example case)?

Comment: @ONCE_AGAIN *im not allowed to use vectors as my memory cap is 64 mb* -- Do you know what a vector is?  You say your memory cap is 64mb, but you're using non-valid C++ syntax that can easily blow out the stack memory.

Comment: just to ask, will it take too much memory to set it up as a strcmp between strings (one being a string array with the values that you enter and the other being a constant string "DA")?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, i know what a vector is, but is there a way to resolve it without using them. I don't have a problem with using them, but the exercise itself is not in the vector category. And if you need to know something about our competition  system, if you go SLIGHTLY out of bounds than it will be marked as completely false. Sorry for the confusion, english isn't my first language

Comment: *but the exercise itself is not in the vector category.* -- So how are you going to accomplish things such as `int a[n];` when it is not C++?   Second, did you read my comment about the stack memory?  If `n` is large enough, your usage of that invalid syntax will lead to a crash due to stack memory exhaustion.  So your only way out is to use `vector`, or use `new[]`, or hope and pray that `n` is small enough and the fake C++ syntax doesn't blow up.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thing is, both n and sprt are supposed to be <1000